# Windows shortcut to app mode

Tags: windows, windows-10

In Windows (from 8.1, still applicable in 10) when using a shortcut to start/switch-to an application (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd>) and that application is already running multiple times, the functionality behaves two ways:

#### Mode 1

I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> and release it an I'm switched into the first instance of the app. I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> (so press the number twice without releasing the Windows button) and I'm switched into the 2nd running instance of the app.

#### Mode 2

I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> and release it and I see clean desktop and AeroPeak on all the running instances. I'm switched to the instance when I click on the preview or hit enter. I can also move between instances by clicking <kbd>left</kbd>-<kbd>right</kbd> buttons and switch to any of those when hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The problem I'm having that Windows is switching between these 'modes' without any apparent reason. I think it is mostly when I dock/undock machine or connect additional monitors. I there a way how to control it?

Special question: When Windows decides to switch modes it also reorders the instances (so if I have 2 browser windows then the one which was previously the 1st is not 2nd). What's up with that? Does anyone have any explanation of insight into this?